# incorrect but working src field in routing table

Tags: routes, hostname, archlinux

I have a strange problem with my routing table on my raspberry pi running arch linux.

```
greg@pi etc]$ uname -a
Linux pi 3.6.11-2-ARCH+ #1 PREEMPT Mon Dec 31 23:00:25 UTC 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I have the pi setup for a static IP address. Using netcfg and net-auto-wired services.

I am also using nmbd service as part of samba to allow me to ping the device by its hostname
Strange thing is, the static ip I have assigned the device is not the ip that I am getting replies from when I communicate by the hostname.

Looking at the routing table seems to suggest the problem:

```
[greg@pi ~]$ ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 204
192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.20  metric 204
[greg@pi ~]$
```

My interface settings:

```
[greg@pi ~]$ ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fec9:1caf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:c9:1c:af  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1127  bytes 93818 (91.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 684  bytes 76203 (74.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ifb0: flags=130<BROADCAST,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        ether e2:bb:30:e7:d0:8a  txqueuelen 32  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ifb1: flags=130<BROADCAST,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        ether 8a:e3:26:d4:38:b8  txqueuelen 32  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 16436
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 20  bytes 1890 (1.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 1890 (1.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

From another pc on the network I have verified that both IPs refers to the same interface (They have the same physical addresses).

Example of communications working:

```
[2013-01-22 00:37.47]  ~
[GKuhn.GKUHN-L01] ? ping pi

Pinging pi [192.168.1.20] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.20: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.20:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 36ms, Average = 12ms

[2013-01-22 00:37.54]  ~
[GKuhn.GKUHN-L01] ? ping 192.168.1.3

Pinging 192.168.1.3 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.3: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.3: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.3: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.3: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.3:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 26ms, Average = 8ms
```

Now as I said this setup is still working. But I am confused and would like to know 
a) How this is actually working 
b) How to fix it

P.S. Looking at my logs (below comes from "everything.log") I see some more references to dhcpcd

```
Jan  1 01:00:09 pi dhcpcd[108]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.20
Jan  1 01:00:10 pi dhcpcd[108]: eth0: acknowledged 192.168.1.20 from 192.168.1.1
Jan  1 01:00:10 pi dhcpcd[108]: eth0: checking for 192.168.1.20
Jan  1 01:00:14 pi dhcpcd[108]: eth0: leased 192.168.1.20 for 3600 seconds
```

However I have no custom config for this process. 
Any suggestions on where I should be looking to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Some more detail:
The raspberry **was** connected to an edimax wifi usb dongle so I had set it up with this interface in mind as well. I had been using the arch [Wireless Setup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup) page as a guide.

I installed wireless_tools, dhcpcd (if it wasn't already I can't recall) and netcfg. I also installed net-auto-wired and net-auto-wireless in the hope that a connection would just work depending on which one was plugged in.

Below are the pertinent configuration files:

```
[greg@pi multi-user.target.wants]$ pwd
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants
[greg@pi multi-user.target.wants]$ ls
cronie.service          openntpd.service  sshdgenkeys.service
dhcpcd@eth0.service     remote-fs.target  syslog-ng.service
net-auto-wired.service  smbd.service
nmbd.service            sshd.service
[greg@pi multi-user.target.wants]$
```

dhcpcd@eth0.service:

```
[greg@pi multi-user.target.wants]$ cat dhcpcd\@eth0.service
[Unit]
Description=dhcpcd on %I
Wants=network.target
Before=network.target
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/dhcpcd-%I.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpcd -q -w %I
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/dhcpcd -x %I

[Install]
Alias=multi-user.target.wants/dhcpcd@eth0.service
```

net-auto-wired.service:

```
[greg@pi multi-user.target.wants]$ cat net-auto-wired.service
[Unit]
Description=Provides automatic netcfg wired connection

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/netcfg
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ifplugd -i $WIRED_INTERFACE -r /etc/ifplugd/netcfg.action -fIns
ExecStop=/usr/bin/netcfg iface-down $WIRED_INTERFACE

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
[greg@pi multi-user.target.wants]$

[greg@pi network.d]$ pwd
/etc/network.d
[greg@pi network.d]$ ls
ethernet-static  examples  interfaces  wlan0-xxx
[greg@pi network.d]$ cat wlan0-xxx
CONNECTION='wireless'
DESCRIPTION='Automatically generated profile by wifi-menu'
INTERFACE='wlan0'
SECURITY='wpa'
ESSID=xxx
IP='dhcp'
KEY=xxx
[greg@pi network.d]$ cat ethernet-static
CONNECTION='ethernet'
DESCRIPTION='A basic static ethernet connection using iproute'
INTERFACE='eth0'
IP='static'
ADDR='192.168.1.3'
ROUTES=('192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1')
GATEWAY='192.168.1.1'
DNS=('192.168.1.1')

## For IPv6 autoconfiguration
#IP6=stateless

## For IPv6 static address configuration
#IP6='static'
#ADDR6=('1234:5678:9abc:def::1/64' '1234:3456::123/96')
#ROUTES6=('abcd::1234')
#GATEWAY6='1234:0:123::abcd'
[greg@pi network.d]$

[greg@pi log]$ cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname
# To share the DHCP lease across OSX and Windows a ClientID is needed.
# Enabling this may get a different lease than the kernel DHCP client.
# Some upstream DHCP servers may also require a ClientID, such as FRITZ!Box.
#clientid

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
option interface_mtu
# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname
noipv4ll

#static dns lookup address
#nohook resolv.conf
[greg@pi log]$
```

If there is anything I have omitted please let me know and I will post it.

A summary of services reported by systemctl:

```
[greg@pi ~]$ systemctl > services
[greg@pi ~]$ cat services
UNIT                        LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION
proc-sys...t_misc.automount loaded active running   Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point
sys-devi...y-ttyAMA0.device loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/dev:f1/tty/ttyAMA0
sys-devi...-net-eth0.device loaded active plugged   ec00
sys-devi...mmcblk0p1.device loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:e624/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1
sys-devi...mmcblk0p2.device loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:e624/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p2
sys-devi...k-mmcblk0.device loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:e624/block/mmcblk0
sys-devi...-net-ifb0.device loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/ifb0
sys-devi...-net-ifb1.device loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/ifb1
sys-devi...ttyprintk.device loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/tty/ttyprintk
sys-module-configfs.device  loaded active plugged   /sys/module/configfs
sys-subs...ices-eth0.device loaded active plugged   ec00
sys-subs...ices-ifb0.device loaded active plugged   /sys/subsystem/net/devices/ifb0
sys-subs...ices-ifb1.device loaded active plugged   /sys/subsystem/net/devices/ifb1
-.mount                     loaded active mounted   /
boot.mount                  loaded active mounted   /boot
dev-mqueue.mount            loaded active mounted   POSIX Message Queue File System
proc-sys...infmt_misc.mount loaded active mounted   Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System
sys-kernel-config.mount     loaded active mounted   Configuration File System
sys-kernel-debug.mount      loaded active mounted   Debug File System
tmp.mount                   loaded active mounted   Temporary Directory
systemd-...ord-console.path loaded active waiting   Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch
systemd-...ssword-wall.path loaded active waiting   Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch
crond.service               loaded failed failed    LEGACY unit for "crond" rc script
cronie.service              loaded active running   Periodic Command Scheduler
dbus.service                loaded active running   D-Bus System Message Bus
dhcpcd@eth0.service         loaded active running   dhcpcd on eth0
getty@tty1.service          loaded active running   Getty on tty1
hwclock.service             loaded active exited    LEGACY unit for "hwclock" rc script
net-auto-wired.service      loaded active running   Provides automatic netcfg wired connection
network.service             loaded active exited    LEGACY unit for "network" rc script
nmbd.service                loaded active running   Samba NetBIOS name server
openntpd.service            loaded active running   OpenNTP Daemon
rc-local.service            loaded active exited    /etc/rc.local Compatibility
smbd.service                loaded active running   Samba SMB/CIFS server
sshd.service                loaded active running   OpenSSH Daemon
syslog-ng.service           loaded active running   System Logger Daemon
systemd-journald.service    loaded active running   Journal Service
systemd-logind.service      loaded active running   Login Service
systemd-remount-fs.service  loaded active exited    Remount Root and Kernel File Systems
systemd-sysctl.service      loaded active exited    Apply Kernel Variables
systemd-...es-setup.service loaded active exited    Recreate Volatile Files and Directories
systemd-...-trigger.service loaded active exited    udev Coldplug all Devices
systemd-udevd.service       loaded active running   udev Kernel Device Manager
systemd-...sessions.service loaded active exited    Permit User Sessions
systemd-...le-setup.service loaded active exited    Setup Virtual Console
dbus.socket                 loaded active running   D-Bus System Message Bus Socket
syslog.socket               loaded active running   Syslog Socket
systemd-initctl.socket      loaded active listening /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe
systemd-journald.socket     loaded active running   Journal Socket
systemd-shutdownd.socket    loaded active listening Delayed Shutdown Socket
systemd-...d-control.socket loaded active listening udev Control Socket
systemd-udevd-kernel.socket loaded active running   udev Kernel Socket
arch-daemons.target         loaded active active    Arch Daemons
basic.target                loaded active active    Basic System
cryptsetup.target           loaded active active    Encrypted Volumes
getty.target                loaded active active    Login Prompts
graphical.target            loaded active active    Graphical Interface
local-fs-pre.target         loaded active active    Local File Systems (Pre)
local-fs.target             loaded active active    Local File Systems
multi-user.target           loaded active active    Multi-User
network.target              loaded active active    Network
remote-fs.target            loaded active active    Remote File Systems
sockets.target              loaded active active    Sockets
swap.target                 loaded active active    Swap
sysinit.target              loaded active active    System Initialization
syslog.target               loaded active active    Syslog
systemd-...iles-clean.timer loaded active waiting   Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

67 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
[greg@pi ~]$
```

Interestingly I tried disabling dhcpcd service as Martin suggested below in the comments and after confirming that it was disabled and rebooting, I saw no change, well pinging the raspberry showed a response from 192.168.1.3 which is different but `ip route show` yielded the same result. I then tried disabling `net-auto-wired` service. I rebooted the raspberry, and I then thought that I had lost access to the  device (headless over ssh) as I hadn't re-enabled dhcpcd service. Interestingly I hadn't and my ip address is now 192.168.1.20.

dhcpcd service is not running at present:

```
[greg@pi log]$ systemctl | grep -i dhcp
[greg@pi log]$
```

This therefore tells me that there has to be some other dhcp mechanism that I am of yet unaware of.

Looking at systemctl and grepping for eth0:

```
[greg@pi log]$ systemctl -a --full | grep -i eth
sys-devices-platform-bcm2708_usb-usb1-1\x2d1-1\x2d1.1-1\x2d1.1:1.0-net-eth0.device loaded active   plugged   ec00
sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device                                              loaded active   plugged   ec00
LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
[greg@pi log]$
```

I am not sure just yet what the above 2 services are but could they be related to the problem?

Comment: Is by any chance the `dhcpcd@` service running? run `systemctl | grep dhcpcd` to see if it's active.

Comment: Hi Martín, Thanks for the reply. Yes it was as part of eth0.service I think:`[greg@pi network.d]$ systemctl | grep dhcpcd
dhcpcd@eth0.service         loaded active running   dhcpcd on eth0` But I also see this: `[greg@pi network.d]$ systemctl status dhcpcd
dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
          Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; disabled)
          Active: inactive (dead)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/dhcpcd.service
`

Comment: It's hard to predict what the issue is, but is obviously an unintentional aliasing. If you could explain step by step, every action you made to configure you network. What files you copied, created, modified, what services you enabled, what commands you ran, etc. It may help us catch the the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to

> a) How this is actually working

Is [IP address aliasing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Configuration#IP_address_aliasing). From the Arch wiki:

> > > IP aliasing is the process of adding more than one IP address to a network interface. With this, one node on a network can have multiple connections to a network, each serving a different purpose.

Now to answer

> b) How to fix it

`192.168.1.3` appears te be the ip that you want to use and you want it to be static, this means that `192.168.1.20` is the ip obtained by dhcpcd, which is also a service that is started according to the contents of your `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` folder. So by disabling this service the problem should go away. You can either run (as root)

```
systemctl disable dhcpcd@eth0.service
```

or

```
rm /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhcpcd@eth0.service
```

Now if you want to use the USB dongle, I suggest you to drop `net-auto-wired` (removing the service in a similar fashion) and use `wicd` or `networkmanager` instead, both can be configured to use static ip, and default to another interface when the first is not present. And they are easier to setup.

Finally, it's not a bad idea to simply use dhcp to get IPs for your interfaces, and configure your router or modem to assign fixed IPs based on MAC Address.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the detailed response, its definitely gotten me closer to the source of the problem. This is starting to make more sense. Unfortunately I have to use a router provided by my ISP and its a bit crappy in terms of interface and settings which is why I wanted to do it on the raspberry side. Please see updated problem description.

Comment: I failed to see the *network.service LEGACY unit for "network" rc script*, so how about disabling that one, and reenabling net auto wired.

Comment: Bingo - the solution to the problem was editing /etc/rc.conf and removing _network_ from the daemons list as you suggested. From my understanding a properly setup systemd should not require the rc initscript system but I am hesitant to disable at present. But whoop I understand it! Thanks a million for the help.